# Bokeh "source" with multiple connected plots

Tags: bokeh

I am of the assumption that this is not possible with Dataframes and ColumnDataSource but interested in any ideas:

To LinkedBrush data between plots I would like to use "source" eg:

```
p1.rect(x="X1", width="W",y=1, height="Val1" source = SourcesfromDF )
p1.rect(x="X1", width="W",y=2, height="Val2" source = SourcesfromDF )
p1.rect(x="X1", width="W",y=3, height="Val3" source = SourcesfromDF )
...
p1.rect(x1="X1", width="W",y=1000 height="Val1000" source = SourcesfromDF )
```

each row in the df needs to have a value for this to work eg:

```
X1  W   Val1   Val2  ... Val1000
12 13    41     52  ...   2100
```

But my data is actually of the structure

```
X1  W   Val1   Val2 ... Val1000
12 13           52  ...   2100
10 11    41         ...    210
 2 14    91     62  ...   
92 13            2  ...
```

(Which can not be plotted)

originating from a dictionary list-with a dictionary:

```
[{'x1':12 , 'x2':13, 'values':{'val2':52 ,'val31':310, 'val1000':2100}}, ...]
```

Which I essentially convert to an un-nested dictionary

```
[{'x1':12 , 'x1':13, 'val2':52 ,'val31':310, 'val1000':2100}
...]
```

to create the above data structure witch has a whole lot of undefined values in it.

To plot the X1 W against each 'val' I create individual plots
from an extracted subset:

```
ValSubset=MyBigDF.loc[MyBigDF[ValX] > 0 ]    
# looking to do this as generically so my 'vals' may be strings etc,
# so the expression should be something like != NaN
```

- a) A nice solution would be to plot all the X1-W values repeatedly against every val1 to valN that is not NaN from a single 'source' in a single plot in a single call.
- b) My second best solution would be to have a single source full on NaN that I can use on multiple plots that allows highlighting of selected glyphs from the common 'source'. (i.e. how can I get a subset of the 'source' that ignores the NaN for the 'vals' I want to plot) (I was reading that Bokeh may support NaN, but read nothing about multiple plots against the same values - but can see a workaround with multiple plot on the same axis)
- c) both a)&b) require a large dataframe/ColumnDataSource that has many NaN fields and for each new "Val_" added each row needs another NaN. Ideal situation would be to plot against a Dictionary (or list) of "Vals"

Comment: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/737